# How do I make my overflow actions appear with a MaterialToolbar that is set as the ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

My `MainActivity` uses a MaterialToolbar as its top app bar. However, once I call `setSupportActionBar`, the Overflow Actions button (the three dots) disappears and I cannot see or click it.

However, if I don't call `setSupportActionBar`, the button appears. I don't like this solution because it forces me to use `Toolbar.onMenuItemClickListener` when I would prefer to simply use `AppCompatActivity.onOptionsMenuSelected` and `setSupportActionBar` as that is how the rest of the app is built.

My `layout/activity_main` code:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_appbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_top_app_bar"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
    ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My `menu/menu_top_app_bar` code:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Here is the `MainActivity` implementation that does not work. The overflow menu option does not show up.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);

        mTextLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_layout);
       
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                // Unknown; allow superclass to handle
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This implementation does work, but I want the above one to work instead:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);

        TextLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to inflate your menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, instead of using the `app:menu` attribute.

Comment: @MikeM. This worked, thanks. I don't know why this wasn't included in the Android Developers Toolbar guide, but it is the only way it works.